# Get Thumbnail data from camera images via WIA 2.0

Tags: c#, wia

I'm trying to use WIA 2.0 (Windows 7) to hook up to a camera (or camera phone, an iPhone, in my case) and download pictures.

Instead of downloading all the pictures onto the HDD or into memory and generate a thumbnail for preview, I'd like to use the WIA 2.0's "Thumbnail Data" property. But the data seems nonsensical. The first and last 3455 bytes of the file are 0xff, with data sandwiched in the middle. If I strip those off and start at position 3456 (What?! Thats the kind of combination an idiot would have on his suitcase!) I still don't get a valid image as far as I can tell.

Here is the code I use when trying to process through the images on the camera. The LoadThumbnail function is supposed to take the binary data and store it in a useful format. I just need to figure out what format that is. MSDN says it is 24-bit RGB in a 32 bit format, but it doesn't look that way if the first 3455 bytes are 0xff.

```
private void GetPictures()
    {
        string camreaid = _camera.DeviceID;
        List<MyPicture> pictureList = new List<MyPicture>();
        foreach (Item i in _camera.Items)
        {
            MyPicture pic = new MyPicture();

            // Get created date property
            foreach (Property p in i.Properties)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p.Name);

                dynamic propertyData = p.get_Value();

                switch(p.Name) {
                    case "Item Name":
                        pic.Name = propertyData;
                        break;
                    case "Item Time Stamp":
                        // created date
                        pic.CreationDate = propertyData.Date;
                        break;
                    case "Thumbnail Data":
                        // thumbnail image
                        pic.LoadThumbnail( propertyData.BinaryData);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Is there a lot of white on the top and the bottom?  Pretty hard to reverse-engineer what format MyPicture.LoadThumbnail() might need.

Comment: No, it happens on every picture (or at least the first 10 on the camera) and they are a random assortment of pictures - me and my friends inside play video games, outdoors shot of a baseball game, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548420(v=vs.85).aspx

It looks like the the Thumbnail data is raw rgb (and you get the width and height of the thumbnail from the properties `WIA_IPC_THUMB_WIDTH` and `_HEIGHT`)

> "... The application then reads the WIA_IPC_THUMBNAIL property for the actual thumbnail data. The thumbnail data should be uncompressed, 24-bits per pixel data aligned on 32-bit boundaries."